# Algorithm for Continuous Number arrangement - Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

i need number arrangement  algorithm or javascript code for following  case

```
input :  [0,0,1,1,3,3,5,5,7,8,8,8,10]

output : [0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,6]
```

Thanks
i try following snippets

```
var array=[];
array[0]=0;
array[1]=0;
array[2]=2;
array[3]=2;
array[4]=5;
array[5]=5;
array[6]=6;

$.each(array,function(i,val){  
   if(i==0){
     prev=eval(val);
   }else{
     if(prev!=val){
       if(val!=eval(prev)+1){          
      array[i]=eval(prev+1);
      prev=eval(prev+1);;
       }else{
          prev=val;
       }
     }
   }
});
```

Comment: Posting 2 sets of numbers doesn't help. You need to tell us the algo that you're looking for, and what you've already tried...

Comment: can you explain the concept of this.? because there is no relation between the input and the output.

Comment: Can Make your specifications clear .

Comment: The algorithm seems to be counting how many numbers, and repeating the "count" depending on the occurrence in the first array.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I don't understand where you don't see a relation. Obviously it's counting the different numbers.

Comment: Note that you very very rarely need to use eval, so cut it out!

Comment: "Missing number arrangement" is approaching zero usefulness as a description of what you are trying to accomplish, Arun. @Christoph must be clairvoyant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for that:

```
var c = 0,
    array_in = [0,0,1,1,3,3,5,5,7,8,8,8,10],
    array_out = [];
array_out = array_in.map(function(a,i,arr){return (arr[i] > arr[i-1])?++c:c});

// array_out == [0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,6]
```

[See the example](http://jsfiddle.net/BcTQB/)

Comment: @Arun you are welcome. Please note the browser compatibility. If you need to support IE<9 you need a shim for the map method like stated in the article I linked in the answer (See section "Compatibility").

Answer (score -1):

This could be done when elements are in sorted order .

```
A[n]=[0,0,1,1,3,3,5,5,7,8,8,8,10] // as these these are in sorted order .
int B[n];

for(int i=1,B[0]=0;i<n;i++)
{
   if(A[i]==A[i-1])
      B[i]=B[i-1];
   else 
      B[i]=B[i-1]+1;
}
```

Finally u'll get B[n]=[0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,6];

Comment: `A[n]` and `B[n]={0}` are syntax errors and omitting the `{}` is very bad style too.